# How to use powershell to register each task?

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of task in .xml format. How do I use powershell to register each task from the folder of tasks? Such as Task_1.xml, Task_2.xml etc in a folder called TASK_FOLDER.

Comment: What kind of task is stored in Task_1.xml? What did you try so far?

Comment: Check out [Register-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) with its parameter `-TaskPath`. If you get an error message, provide your code and your error please.

Comment: Take a look at [schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks).

Comment: `-TaskPath` refers to the location the final task will be stored in, not any source definition, XML etc... I think `-Xml` may be the parameter we're after. [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505402/4749264), let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML is valid.  For my testing I exported a simple task from my system.

One thing that's a little misleading is the -Xml parameter takes a string not an actual XML object. so we need to give it a monolithic string.

```
$XML = Get-Content c:\Temp\TestTask.xml -Raw
Register-ScheduledTask -XML $XML -TaskName TestTask
```

> Note: `Get-Content` normally returns an array.  The -Raw parameter instructs it to return a single string.

This seemed to work.  However I suspect you're going to have an issue, because even with the -XML parameter the -TaskName parameter is mandatory.  We need some options so we can automate the task name as well as the configuration.

The first Idea  could be to just use the filenames, that might look something like this:

```
$TaskFiles = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\tasks 

ForEach( $TaskFile in $TaskFiles )
{
    $TaskName  = $TaskFile.BaseName # Use base name, to strip the .xml extension
    $XmlString = Get-Content $TaskFile.FullName -Raw
    Register-ScheduledTask -Xml $XmlString -TaskName $TaskName -User MyUser -Password MyPassword
}
```

A second option may be to parse the  tag inside the task XML file.  In my case the tag looks like: `<URI>\TestTask</URI>`. So, you can see this is pretty close to the name.  We'll need a formal XML object to to work with the URI, but we'll extract the string data when we need to run `Register-ScheduledTask`

This approach might look something like:

```
$TaskFiles = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\tasks 

ForEach( $TaskFile in $TaskFiles )
{
    $TaskXml  = [XML]( Get-Content $TaskFile.FullName )
    $TaskName = $TaskXml.task.RegistrationInfo.URI.split("\")[-1]    
    Register-ScheduledTask -Xml $TaskXml.OuterXml -TaskName $TaskName -User MyUser -Password MyPassword
}
```

> Note: `$TaskXml.OuterXML` refers to the XML's string representation.

> Warning: I don't know the tasks schema that well, can't gurantee the
> `<URI>` tag is always present.

A few things to point out for both examples:

1. The `-User` & `-Password` parameters will override what's in the file.  This will accommodate both when the password has changed since the XML file was generated or when an obsolete or defunct account is in the XML file.
2. Strictly speaking I'm not sure password is required just to register. but, be advised you cannot enter it as a secure string and generally you don't want to hard code passwords.  If this is for interactive we could probably prompt for the password then extract from the credential object.  Either way, as a security concern, be aware of it.
3. I didn't test either of these, as I don't have tons of task XML files laying around.

For completeness I also tested schtasks.exe, which I've used for this before.

```
schtasks.exe /Create /XML C:\TestTask.xml /TN TestTask
```

> Output: SUCCESS: The scheduled task "TestTask" has successfully been
> created.

Notice that schtasks.exe also requires the name (/TN).  You could wrap it in a loop similar to the above examples though. I didn't test updating the username or password.

As I mentioned in the other discussions scheduled tasks can be tough to work with.  I really recommend you take a look at the [documentation for Register-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps).  Beyond that you should have enough to work through your issue.

Comment: My tests were only using a very simple task. I’ll take a look at the specific error when I get a chance.

Comment: this is the error -------------------------------------------  Register-ScheduledTask : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
(30,8):UserId:
At line:7 char:5
+     Register-ScheduledTask -Xml $XmlString -TaskName $TaskName
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070534,Register-ScheduledTask

Comment: Again, I'm at a disadvantage.  That said, I was able to reproduce the error by putting a non-existent user in the XML file, in the `<UserId>`  tag.  That means the user cited in the XML file doesn't exist.  However, you can / should override that using the `-User` & `-Password` parameters.  I'm going to update the answer to include.

Comment: Thankyou for all your help. I know it takes a lot of time.